# Django DRF filtering fields in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to **Django DRF** and I'm trying to write a more organized code since the one below lacks the correct approach.

I have 2 API endpoints:

1. /api/order/info - which shows all the order fields
2. /api/order/status - which shows only one field

At the moment I have two serializers and two views as follows:

```
serializers.py

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_id', 'data', 'status']
    
class OrderStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['status']



views.py

# /api/order/info - retrieves all fields
class OrderInfo(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    
    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(pk=self.request.data['uuid'])
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
    
# /api/order/status - retrives just one field, the status
class OrderStatus(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderStatusSerializer # a serializer just for this
    
    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(pk=self.request.data['uuid'])
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

The problem: the code works as expected, but it is pretty clear that it is **duplicate**!

I'm creating a new serializer for just filtering one field, but I strongly believe that DRF makes this easier in some way.

Could you please suggest a better approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this solve your problem?

- Views

```py
class OrderBase(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    
    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(pk=self.request.data['uuid'])
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404


class OrderInfo(OrderBase):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    

class OrderStatus(OrderBase):
    serializer_class = OrderStatusSerializer
```

- Serializers

```py
class MetaBase:
    model = Order
    fields = '__all__'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(MetaBase):
        fields = ['order_id', 'data', 'status']
    
class OrderStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(MetaBase):
        fields = ['status']
```

This is called inheritance ;)

Comment: Yes, definitively a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using django rest framework `to_representation` method to send only the fields you need.

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_id', 'data', 'status']

    def to_representation(self, instance) -> OrderedDict:
        fields = super(OrderSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        ret = OrderedDict()
        # your logic to filter out fields based on the request path
        return ret
```